# Why would apache-maven-3.5.3-bin work and apache-maven-3.8.4-bin wouldn't work

Tags: maven, jenkins

I was testing the move from a Jenkins docker image to another using Thinbacvkup and restore the backup and restore went well and of course it didn't bring maven with it (No problem there) I went online and got the latest apache maven bin file (apache-maven-3.8.4-bin), extracted and set up the global tool configuration, export M2_HOME ...ETC. BUT for some reason, it didn't work giving me the same message

```
@tmp/durable-e665ee46/script.sh: 1: mvn: not found
```

searched and searched nothing worked, so I went to the original docker and got the same maven from there (apache-maven-3.5.3-bin)edited the configs and all, and it worked but now I wanted to know why did this work and that won't is there something with my project, build or what?

Comment: First M2_HOME is not needed only an entry in the path variable is needed nothing more. So you are using the docker image to run Maven? Or have you downloaded Maven from https://maven.apache.org In Jenkins have you configured in global tools configuration ?

Comment: Why are you not referencing maven from [Global Tools](https://devopspilot.com/content/jenkins/tutorials/common/03-global-tool-configurations) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise no I'm running Jenkins in docker, not maven I got the apache-maven-3.8.4-bin and referenced it in the global tool configuration referencing its path when it didn't work i tried setting M2_HOME.NOthing worked until i returned to apache-maven-3.5.3-bin

Comment: @IanW I did that didn't work with 3.8.4

Comment: @Datatraveler, did my answer below solve your issue? Consider marking as accepted and/or upvote if so.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a Docker image, but had no problem on a clean install, no plugins,

**Global Tool Configuration** ( `/configureTools/` ), add maven configuration:
[image: Global Tools Config - Maven]

Create job with **Invoke top-level maven step**, choose same maven version:
[image: Job - Maven step]

If a **pipeline** job, then the reference would be [tools](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#supported-tools):

```
tools {
    maven 'maven-3.8.4' 
}
```

or [withMaven](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/#plugin-content-usage):

```
withMaven(
    // Maven installation declared in the Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration"
    maven: 'maven-3.8.4',
```

Works fine. I did not set M2_HOME or add to PATH; Tool configuration takes care of that.

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\jenkins\.jenkins.2.322.new\workspace\M-Foo
Unpacking https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.8.4/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.zip to C:\Users\jenkins\.jenkins.2.322.new\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\maven-3.8.4 on Jenkins
[M-Foo] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\jenkins\.jenkins.2.322.new\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\maven-3.8.4\bin\mvn.cmd -version && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: C:\Users\jenkins\.jenkins.2.322.new\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\maven-3.8.4
Java version: 1.8.0_312, vendor: Temurin, runtime: C:\Tools\Java\jdk8\jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
Finished: SUCCESS
```

> **Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
>
> Maven home: C:\Users\jenkins.jenkins.2.322.new\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\maven-3.8.4**

**Note**: you must have [proxy set up](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation) properly for the "Install from Apache" to populate for "Install automatically".

If you un-tick "**Install automatically**", then you must input the **MAVEN_HOME** (which should really be labelled M2_HOME) and then choose that.

[image: Global Tools Config - Maven; manual]

[image: Job - Maven step; manual]

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\jenkins\.jenkins.2.322.new\workspace\M-Foo
[M-Foo] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\Tools\apache-maven\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\mvn.cmd -version && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Tools\apache-maven\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_312, vendor: Temurin, runtime: C:\Tools\Java\jdk8\jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
Finished: SUCCESS
```

> **Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
>
> Maven home: C:\Tools\apache-maven\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin..**